# Refactoring exceptions to aspect?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

We have a large code base that was developed in Spring MVC. The following code repeats all over the place.

```
 public @ResponseBody BaseResponse<String> getSomething() {
    BaseResponse<String> response = new BaseResponse<String>();
    try {
        //something
    } catch (Exception e) {
        BaseError be = ExceptionHandler.errorResponse(e);
        response.setError(be);
    }
    return response;
}
```

I am curious if this can be refactored or simplified using aspects?

ie: ExceptionHandler can be called within the aspect but how about setting the error in response?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using Java8, I would do it with a helper method taking a lambda, it's minimal overhead in both code and runtime, and doesn't need a new dependency like AspectJ. If you're using Java7 or less, AspectJ could be an option, using `around()` advice is a typical textbook example for your use case.

Comment: Using JDK 6. will look into your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your situation with plain Java + native AspectJ because I am not a Spring user. But the aspect as such and its pointcut should be the same in Spring AOP, only the aspect also needs to be a `@Component`.

**Several dummy classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ResponseBody {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class BaseError {
    private Exception e;

    public BaseError(Exception e) {
        this.e= e;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class ExceptionHandler {
    public static BaseError errorResponse(Exception e) {
        return new BaseError(e);
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class BaseResponse<T> {
    private String body;
    private String error = "OK";

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public void setError(BaseError be) {
        error = be.getMessage();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BaseResponse [body=" + body + ", error=" + error + "]";
    }
}
```

**Driver application:**

There are two target methods returning `BaseResponse<String>`, basically doing the same as your sample method, throwing exceptions randomly, but with exception handling stripped off. I guess this is what you want to achieve.

There also is anoter method not to be targeted by the aspect (as a negative test case).

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.Random;

public class Application {
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(application.doSomething());
            System.out.println(application.getSomething());
            System.out.println(application.getSomethingElse());
        }
    }

    public String doSomething() {
        return "Doing something";
    }

    public @ResponseBody BaseResponse<String> getSomething() {
        BaseResponse<String> response = new BaseResponse<String>();
        if (RANDOM.nextBoolean())
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot get something");
        response.setBody("getting something");
        return response;
    }

    public @ResponseBody BaseResponse<String> getSomethingElse() {
        BaseResponse<String> response = new BaseResponse<String>();
        if (RANDOM.nextBoolean())
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot get something else");
        response.setBody("getting something else");
        return response;
    }
}
```

**Error handling aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.BaseError;
import de.scrum_master.app.BaseResponse;
import de.scrum_master.app.ExceptionHandler;

@Aspect
public class ErrorHandler {
    @Around("execution(de.scrum_master.app.BaseResponse<String> *(..))")
    public Object handleError(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        try {
            return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            BaseError be = ExceptionHandler.errorResponse(e);
            BaseResponse<String> response = new BaseResponse<String>();
            response.setBody("uh-oh!");
            response.setError(be);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**Console log:**

Here you can see nicely how each `BaseResponse` is either created and populated by cour application code or by the error handling aspect:

```
Doing something
BaseResponse [body=getting something, error=OK]
BaseResponse [body=uh-oh!, error=cannot get something else]
Doing something
BaseResponse [body=uh-oh!, error=cannot get something]
BaseResponse [body=getting something else, error=OK]
Doing something
BaseResponse [body=getting something, error=OK]
BaseResponse [body=getting something else, error=OK]
Doing something
BaseResponse [body=getting something, error=OK]
BaseResponse [body=getting something else, error=OK]
Doing something
BaseResponse [body=getting something, error=OK]
BaseResponse [body=uh-oh!, error=cannot get something else]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I appreaciate it. Only a quick question I have, we actually have the same design. Would BaseResponse<T> work in this case for the aspect?

Comment: No, this would be illogical. Outside the class definition you cannot use generic type variables only known inside. If you want to match all base responses, just use `BaseResponse` or, if you prefer that, `BaseResponse<*>`. Alternatively, make your aspect generic if you see any value in that. But then you have to declare it `abstract` and create concrete subclasses of it, such as `@Aspect public class StringErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler<String> {}`